# Scanning and assigning a negative value from a file to an int

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner, negative-number

So, I have an assignment for my class to write a program that reads numeric (int) data from a file, performs calculations on the data, and then prints the results in a format. However, the calculations performed are dependent upon how hot it is.

First, it'll read the Fahrenheit temperature and then calculate the temperature in Celsius.

If the temperature is 50 degrees or less, it'll read the wind speed and calculate the wind chill factor in Fahrenheit and Celsius, printing them out, along with wind speed in meters per second.

If the temperature is 80 or more, it'll read the relative humidity, calculate the heat index for both Fahrenheit and Celsius, and then print them out.

If the temperature is between 50 and 80, then it'll just print out the Fahrenheit and Celsius temperatures.

My issue is that the program isn't reading negative numbers from the file.

Here's my program, (Note: I noticed this while I was in the middle of programming it, hence why there is an empty else-if-statement and an empty else-statement, and the tempo variables were removed from the code while I tried to debug a few calculation errors that are probably being caused by this issue):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program2{
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        //Creating file input, scanner, and exception catch

        FileInputStream inf = null;
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            inf = new FileInputStream("weatherData.txt");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("You've rolled a Nat 1! Critical Failure! The file you're looking for could not be found! To top it off, this program will"
                                    + " now close!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        in = new Scanner(inf);

        //Creating variables

        String a;           //Testing string
        int tempF,          //Temperature Fahrenheit
            windSpeedMPH,   //Wind Speed in Miles per hour
            relHum;         //Relative Humidity
        double tempC,       //Temperature Celsius
               heatIndex,   //Heat Index
               windSpeedMPS,//Wind Speed in Meters per Second
               windChillF,  //Wind Chill factor in Fahrenheit
               windChillC,  //Wind Chill factor in Celsius
               tempo1,      //tempo1-13 are temporary variables to hold values
               tempo2,      //in order to simplify calculations
               tempo3,
               tempo4,
               tempo5,
               tempo6,
               tempo7,
               tempo8,
               tempo9,
               tempo10,
               tempo11,
               tempo12,
               tempo13;

        //Beginning calculation and output

        while(in.hasNext()) {
            //Testing while loop

            //a = in.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(a);

            //Assigning Fahrenheit Temperature

            tempF = in.nextInt();

            //Calculating tempC

            tempC = tempF - 32;
            tempC = tempC * 0.556;
            //System.out.println(tempC);

            //Selection structures for calculations and outputs

            if (tempF <= 50) {
                windSpeedMPH = in.nextInt();
                //System.out.println(windSpeedMPH);

                windChillF = (35.74 + (0.6215 * tempF) - (35.75 * (Math.pow(windSpeedMPH, 0.16))) + ((0.4275 * tempF) * Math.pow(windSpeedMPH, 0.16)));
                //System.out.println(windChillF);

                System.out.println();    //Gives whitespace to separate blocks of data and make the first block visible.
                System.out.printf("%-18s%-21s%10s\n", "Fahrenheit Temp", "Wind Speed (mph)", "Feels Like");
                System.out.printf("%15d%19d%15.1f\n", tempF, windSpeedMPH, windChillF);

                windSpeedMPS = windSpeedMPH / 2.237;

                windChillC = (35.74 + (0.6215 * tempC) - (35.75 * (Math.pow(windSpeedMPS, 0.16))) + ((0.4275 * tempC) * Math.pow(windSpeedMPS, 0.16)));
                //System.out.println(windChillC);

                System.out.printf("%15s%19s%15s\n","Celsius Temp", "Wind Speed (mps)", "Feels Like");
                System.out.printf("%15.1f%19.1f%15.1f\n", tempC, windSpeedMPS, windChillC);
            } 
            else if (tempF >= 80) {

            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my input file, first column is the Fahrenheit temperature, and the second column is either the wind speed in miles per hour or the relative humidity **(Edit: the only way to know if the number in the second column is the wind speed to relative humidity is to look if the temperature is either 50 or below (wind speed) or if it's 80 or above (relative humidity))**.

```
52
-4   16
42   12
21   22
48   20
-27   18
68
62
33    0
11    2
76
0    9
12   20
79
31   31
4    8
103   98
31   17
-7   33
-16   17
36   60
-6   22
91   25
-22    5
93   88
97   12
-10   41
40   51
86   87
87   95
4   43
70
45   10
31   12
-11   33
55
104   81
-24    9
38   33
41   30
60
75
-21   11
30    2
38   23
101   88
55
21   59
83   16
15   45
-16   31
28   13
93   74
45   37
31   50
64
100   54
2    2
96   12
42   15
71
39   32
-23   15
29    9
-22   56
42    7
62
22   26
49   16
45   45
42   39
46   59
105   14
-11   28
-20   31
102   66
51
-29   14
40   46
48   26
-9   52
```

Comment: Java, not JavaScript

Comment: *This is my input file, first column is the Fahrenheit temperature, and the second column is either the wind speed in miles per hour or the relative humidity.* - What is the criteria to determine which is what i.e. which one is `wind speed in miles per hour` and which one is `relative humidity`?